# external links not working html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have created a click to show option on one of my client's website. Which is working perfectly there.
Its respective code is given below.

```
<style>
a{padding:0;margin:0;color:#009cbb;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;}
</style>
<p>
<div><a href="#welcome" onclick="toggle_visibility('welcome');">Welcome</a></div>
<div id="welcome" style="display:none;">This is test</div>

<div><a href="#focus" onclick="toggle_visibility('focus');">Focus</a></div>
<div id="focus" style="display:none;">This is test2
</div>

<div><a href="#cataracts" onclick="toggle_visibility('cataracts');">Cataracts</a></div>
<div id="cataracts" style="display:none;">This is test2
</div>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.display == 'block')
e.style.display = 'none';
else
e.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

When i link test1 from an external page Its should display test1 and keep close the other 2 but the problem is when I click on the link it shows all of them as closed.

The linking code is

```
<a href="http://website.com/page.php#welcome" style="color:#009bd9;text-decoration:none;">Read More ></a>
```

Kindly help me when someone click on Read more it displays the welcome message as open and others as closed.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the quick response bro, sorry that didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - tested in IE8, Chrome32 and Fx 24 on windows

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/792TT/)
[<kbd>**Live Demo With Hash**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/792TT/show/#welcome)

```
function toggle_visibility(link) {
  var id = link.hash.substring(1);
  var obj = document.getElementById(id);
  if (obj) obj.style.display = obj.style.display == "block"?"none":"block";
  return false;
}
window.onload=function() {
  var id = location.hash?location.hash.substring(1):"";
  if (id)  document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";
}
```

using this format on each link (which should also be refactored to be unobtrusive)

```
onclick="return toggle_visibility(this);"
```

Please note the ***(this)***

Comment: @mplungjan I edited your code because it was syntactically incorrect. Now that you rolled back, it is incorrect again as you don't close the `'block` string.

Comment: Right - Thanks. Your fix was lost in annoying space changes :/

Comment: @Bangash Try again - perhaps a jsfiddle.net would be useful

Comment: Sorry for the space changes, I tidyupped it in jsfiddle mostly because the html part, the javascript alignments were collateral damage. I respect your coding standards and don't want to enforce anything on your code :D

Answer (score 1):

HA I finally figured out what you want!

So you want the element to be opened on page load if the link ends with `#element_id`.

Your script tag currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
    else
    e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Change it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
        else e.style.display = 'block';
    }

    var parts = window.location.split('#'),
        hash = '';
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        hash = parts[1];
    }    
    if (hash !== '') {
        toggle_visibility(hash);
    }
</script>
```

EDIT:

`window.location.hash` is apparently supported everywhere. You might want to use that instead of `string.split()`

Comment: @Bangash Just tell me this: Have I understood your question correctly? Do you want the element to be visible (opened) on page load if the url contains a `#something` part?

Comment: You may want to do the second part in a window.onload

Comment: I have no issues with location.hash or link.hash in Chrome - you are looking in the wrong documentation - now your code cannot be used by OP any more due to the "fakelocation"

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eB6Lg/6/show/#focus)

```
window.onload = function(){
        toggle_visibility(window.location.hash.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I did not clearly understand your problem, I have modified your function based on my assumptions.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.visibility == 'visible') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        e.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        e.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

Please let us know what are the modifications you find needed.